# Failing to POST NSData of PDF to server

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsdata, nsurlrequest

I have an iPad application in which I need to send a server a PDF file, alongside two POST variables, a user ID and a job ID. I am using the code below to do this:

NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:currentPDFFileName];

```
    NSData *validPDF = [[NSString stringWithString:@"%PDF"] dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if (!(pdfData && [[pdfData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)] isEqualToData:validPDF])) 
    {
        NSLog (@"Not valid");
    }

    NSLog (@"%@", currentPDFFileName);
    NSLog (@"%@", [currentPDFFileName lastPathComponent]);

    //create the body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    //create the POST vars
    NSString *jobID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"jobid\"\r\n\r\n%@", job.jobID];
    NSString *userID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userid\"\r\n\r\n%@", delegate.userID];
    NSString *pdf = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_file\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", [currentPDFFileName lastPathComponent]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", @"----foo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[jobID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", @"----foo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[userID dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", @"----foo"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[pdf dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:pdfData];

    NSMutableURLRequest *pdfRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"]];
    [pdfRequest setValue:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=----foo" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [pdfRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [pdfRequest setHTTPBody:body];
    NSData *pdfDataReply;
    NSURLResponse *pdfResponse;
    NSError *pdfError;
    pdfDataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:pdfRequest returningResponse:&pdfResponse error:&pdfError];

    NSString *pdfResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:pdfDataReply encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog (@"%@", pdfResult);
```

The people on the other end of the connection are saying that they are not receiving the PDF file. I have tried all the usual suspects such as trying to find any nil objects.

Would greatly appreciate if anyone could please lend a hand with this!

Thanks.
Ricky.

Comment: Can you log the values of `[pdfError code]` and `[(NSURLHTTPRequest *)pdfResponse statusCode]` after the request is done sending, and post them here?

Comment: `[pdfError code]` returns 0, and (I think you meant)`[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)pdfResponse statusCode]` caused an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Sorry about that mixup, I did mean Response instead of Request. You did try to log that value as an integer, not an object, right? If so, can you verify that the Response object exists at all after the request?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was an issue with the boundaries. I needed to add one at the end, after pdfData was added. Thank you for your help.